# Cannot toggle class to label in forms

Tags: javascript, forms, label

I was working on a modal component in Angular and was trying to toggle a class state on a custom input checkbox on clicking on the label, but it didn't work, I thought it was something with material or else with Angular, but also tried with plain HTML and vanilla JS and it does not allow to change or toggle a class in the label. How could this be? Is there something I am missing with the label click behavior? If you click directly on the input it adds the class 'active' but if clicked the 'M' it doesn't. I am hiding the input from the view since I am styling it to look different.

Here is a piece of code for trying here:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.form-check-label');
  elems.forEach((e) => e.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(e.classList);
  }, false));
}, false);

function checkInput(elem) {
  let checkMark = elem.querySelector('input');
  checkMark.checked = !checkMark.checked;
}
```

```css
.form-check-label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label 
onClick = "this.classList.toggle('active');"
class="form-check-label" 
for="Monday">
  <input 
  class="form-check-input" 
  type="checkbox" 
  id="Monday" 
  value="Monday" />
  <span class="day-week">
   M
  </span>
</label>

<br />
<br />

<div 
onClick = "this.classList.toggle('active');checkInput(this);"
class="form-check-label" 
>
  <input 
  class="form-check-input" 
  type="checkbox" 
  value="Monday" />
  <span class="day-week">
   M
  </span>
</div>
```

If I change the label for a div, then it works. You can check the class state change in the browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a interesting case which seems to be related to the behaviour of `input` controlled by `label`. It can be observed that the `click` on `label` generate actually 2 `click` events, first coming from `span` and second (which seems to be a browser synthetic event nevertheless "real") from `input`, which sets the focus on `input` element, this is most obvious when using a `text` type `input`. So, the first `click` sets the class while the second removes it, that happens almost instantaneous.

As a simple solution is to discard the `click` event generated by `input` with `event.stopPropagation()`, although it will disable a real click on `checkbox`:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.form-check-label');
  elems.forEach((e) => e.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(e);
  }, false));
}, false);

function checkInput(elem) {
  let checkMark = elem.querySelector('input');
  checkMark.checked = !checkMark.checked;
}
```

```css
.form-check-label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label 
onClick = "this.classList.toggle('active');"
class="form-check-label" 
for="Monday">
  <input 
  onClick = "event.stopPropagation();"
  class="form-check-input" 
  type="checkbox" 
  id="Monday" 
  value="Monday" />
  <span class="day-week">
   M
  </span>
</label>

<br />
<br />

<div 
onClick = "this.classList.toggle('active');checkInput(this);"
class="form-check-label" 
>
  <input 
  class="form-check-input" 
  type="checkbox" 
  value="Monday" />
  <span class="day-week">
   M
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use the `checked` state of the checkbox instead of controlling the checked state manually.

This is different when using Angular or React, but then you most likely control the checked state instead.

```js
let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.form-check-label > input[type="checkbox"]');
elems.forEach((e) => e.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (e.checked) {
    e.parentElement.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    e.parentElement.classList.remove('active');
  }
}, false));
```

```css
.form-check-label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-check-label.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label class="form-check-label" for="Monday">
  <input
    class="form-check-input" 
    type="checkbox" 
    id="Monday" 
    value="Monday" />
    <span class="day-week">
      M
    </span>
</label>
```